# How do I convert a string to lowercase?

Tags: cs50

I don't know how to convert a word into complete lowercase in cs50. I have to convert words into lowercase to check it properly.
Below is my code so far

```
bool check(const char *word) {
    char *lword[strlen(word)];
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        lword[i] = tolower(int
        word[i]);
    }
    node *current;
    int hashnum = hash(word);
    if (table[hashnum] == NULL)
        return false;
    current = table[hashnum];
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->word, word) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration `char *lword[strlen(word)];` is a problem. it declares `lword` as an array of *strings* (aka char*). An array of *chars* would be more appropriate. (Also, program would probably complain when `lword` is sent as an argument to `hash` function.) Don't forget to declare the lower case word large enough to accommodate the null-terminator, and null-terminate it.  Don't forget to send the lower-case word to hash, instead of the original word.

Comment: You're welcome.[ Here's how to say "thank you" on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)